# Getting keyboard input in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I have been searching around and trying to fix this for hours. I have two scripts, one labeled main.py, and the other menu.py. I am trying to use a variable from main.py to control the actions of menu.py. The variable is set to the last keyboard input, in the main.py script, it does what it's supposed to. However, when I try to do it in menu.py, nothing happens, not error thrown, nor does the original animation I was trying to use happen. I have omitted parts of the code that I don't think are part of the problem to make it easier to read.

main.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

WIDTH = 512
HEIGHT = 416
FPS = 20
VERSION = "0.0.3"
FULLSCREEN = False

import pygame,sys,os,time

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

alpha_display = display.convert_alpha()
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
keyPressed = 0

sys.path.insert(0, "scripts/")
from pygame.locals import *
from media import *
import color
import menu

def run():
    display.fill(color.BLACK)

    if (menu.active == True):
        menu.update()

    else:
        pass

while (True): # Code to run loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == QUIT):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            keyPressed = event.key
        elif (event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
            keyPressed = 0

    run()
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

menu.py code:

```
from __main__ import *

page = "main"
selObj = 1
active = True

class o:
    dee = False
def update():
    if o.dee == False:
        o.dee = True
        global page
        global selObj
        global active

    if page == "main": # Main menu
        if (keyPressed == pygame.K_RETURN):
            if (selObj == 1):
                page = "singleplayer"
            elif (selObj == 2):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        if (keyPressed == pygame.K_UP):
            selObj -= 1
        elif (keyPressed == pygame.K_DOWN):
            selObj += 1

        if (selObj >= 3):
            selObj = 1
        elif (selObj <= 0):
            selObj = 2

        if (selObj == 1):
            print("test1"
        elif (selObj == 2):
            print("test2")
```

Comment: not sure what's wrong but from __main__ import * looks weird to me. Have you tried from main import *? Also I can recommend this boilerplate code: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation/creating-pygame-window

Comment: @robert The line of code "from __ main __ import *" will import everything from the script that imports it, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found your problem. You are looking for pygame events in the `update()` function (by using `keypressed`), but you never call that function in the pygame events loop. I don't know if somewhere in the lines you left out you initialize `keyPressed`, but from what I see you don't (which should raise a `ValueError` exception). If you did initialize `keyPressed` in the menu.py file, you are not transferring the changed value from main.py to menu.py. The way I would recommend to fix that would be to call `menu.update()` within the event loop and have `keyPressed` as an argument.

```
from __main__ import *

page = "main"
selObj = 1
active = True

class o:
    dee = False
def update(keyPressed):#<----#
    if o.dee == False:
        o.dee = True
        global page
        global selObj
        global active

    if page == "main": # Main menu
        if (keyPressed == pygame.K_RETURN):
...
```

and in the main file:

```
    ... 
def run():
    display.fill(color.BLACK)

    if (menu.active == True):
        menu.update(keyPressed)#<-------#

    else:
        pass   
    while (True): # Code to run loop
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if (event.type == QUIT):
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    keyPressed = event.key
                elif (event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
                    keyPressed = 0
                menu.update(keyPressed)#<----#
            run()
            pygame.display.update()
            fpsClock.tick(FPS)
    ...
```

You may have to modify your code further to make sure that your menu does not reset each time the mouse moves.
Hope this helped.